# Is it possible to call JavaScript functions from an HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to call functions by writing their name in an input box.

Some of the functions I would like to be callable are `calc()`, `min()`, `hide()` and `show()`. These functions should be able to be triggered by one input field and 1 button element.

Something along the lines of the basic functions in the browser console.

Comment: If you want to allow the client to input `calc()` to execute the function rather than just `calc` without `()` then this [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lug8ns91/) I have created might be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. If you can pass the function name from the text input, get it into JavaScript and you can execute that function there. But you have to store those function at a global level to access them from anywhere. Either in a var or you can add `var _this = this;` and call the methods on `_this`

For example:

```
_this.foo = function () {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

Entering `foo` into text input and getting this in JavaScript, you can check if that function exists.

Like this:

```
function handleClick(functionName) {
    var func = _this[functionName];
    if (func && typeof func === 'function') {
        func();
    }
}
```

This will check if there is a function with name passed exists and if it's a function or not. And if its a function it will invoke it.

Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lug8ns91/) suggested by [NewToJS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4169803/newtojs).

Comment: The OP doesn't need to change the existing functions at all. A simple piece of `regex` and `replace` can be used to allow the inputs of **function call** rather than **function name**. Here is a working demo [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lug8ns91/)

Comment: Yes that will work just fine. Thanks for the link. Adding it to the answer.

Comment: Very welcome, I thought about posting it as a answer but since others have answered I thought it would be better to write a Jsfiddle but being offered different methods can be useful hence sharing that.

Comment: Sure that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this approach I declare a dictionary where keys are functions names represented as strings. And values are declared functions (`calc(), min() etc.`).
After enter button hit `input` value will be read and matched with dictionary. If dictinary has `input` value key then appropriate function will be called.

Using jQuery:

```js
function calc() {
  return 'calc';
}

function min() {
  return 'min';
}

const funcDict = {
  'calc': calc(),
  'min': min()
}

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var inputVal = $('#inpt').val();
  if (funcDict.hasOwnProperty(inputVal)) {
    console.log(funcDict[inputVal]);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="inpt" id="inpt" />
<button id="btn">Enter</button>
```

Without jQuery:

```js
function calc() {
  return 'calc';
}

function min() {
  return 'min';
}

const funcDict = {
  'calc': calc(),
  'min': min()
}

function onClickHandler(e) {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('inpt').value;

  if (funcDict.hasOwnProperty(inputVal)) {
    console.log(funcDict[inputVal]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="inpt" id="inpt" />
<button id="btn" onClick="onClickHandler()">Enter</button>
```

Comment: You could clearly state your answer uses `jQuery` since the OP hasn't tagged it in the question.

Comment: Very good, now are you going to explain how it works so the OP and future viewers can understand the source code rather than expecting them to just copy/paste it. Understanding the source code is important if changes are needed at a later date.

Comment: Important to note that this code works 'stateless'. The functions are only called once, inside the dictionary. So if for example the function would generate a random string, the dictionary will still always hold the same string.